# The meaning of "earth" in 18th-century chemistry/mineralogy

Tags: meaning, nouns, meaning-in-context, synonyms, terminology

Just today I came across an article describing origin of the name for Yttrium (an element in the periodic table of elements)

> In 1787, Karl Arrhenius came across an unusual black rock in an old
>   quarry at Ytterby, near Stockholm. He thought he had found a new
>   tungsten mineral, and passed the specimen over to Johan Gadolin based
>   in Finland. In 1794, Gadolin announced that it contained a new **'earth'**
>   which made up 38 per cent of its weight. It was called an’ **earth**’
>   because it was yttrium oxide, Y2O3, which could not be reduced further
>   by heating with charcoal.

The source is [here](http://www.rsc.org/periodic-table/element/39/yttrium).

What do "earth" and "new earth" mean in this context? Is this what elements were called before Mendeleev, or is it a synonym for "mineral"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it meant what it still means today

***[Earth](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/earth):***

> - (Chemistry Any of several metallic oxides, such as alumina or zirconia, that are difficult to reduce and were formerly regarded as elements.

[Earth](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=earth): (Etymonline)

> - Use in old chemistry is from 1728.

From Wikipedia:

> - The chemical term earths was historically applied to certain chemical substances, once thought to be elements, and this name was borrowed from one of the four classical elements of Plato. "Earths" later turned out to be chemical compounds, albeit difficult to concentrate, such as rare earths and alkaline earths.
> - ***Earths are metallic oxides, and the corresponding metals were classified into the corresponding groups: rare earth metals and alkaline earth metals.***

Comment: I thought we were supposed to close-vote LMGTFY questions rather than answer them.